# chrome's command line switch for opening tab in background

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, switch

Is there a command line switch for chrome, that would open given url in a new background tab (just like you right click on link and click 'open in new tab')?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately no. The file below is part of Chrome's source that defines all command line switches that the application accepts - I didn't find a switch there that does what you're looking for.

Source: Taken from the latest Chrome build at https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc